# How to set polgon fill type to no color in Mapbox

Tags: color, mapbox-gl-js, fill, addlayer

I'm new to `Mapbox` and I am trying to remove any color in my polygon fill using the Mapbox API. Note: I don't want to set opacity/transparency. I simply want there to be no color. It keeps defaulting to `"#000000"`, even if I comment out the 'fill-color' property. Is there any way to achieve this?

```
 map.addLayer({
            'id': 'us-states',
            'type': 'fill',
            'source': 'us-states',
            'layout': {},
            'paint': {
                //'fill-color': '#333',
                'fill-opacity': 0.8,
                'fill-outline-color': '#000'
            }
    })
```

Comment: Could you point to some image that has the color that you would like to get? Totally transparent is the only no-color that comes into my mind but obviously you have something else in your mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got this to work with:

```
'paint': {
            'fill-color': 'transparent',
            'fill-opacity': 1.0
        }
```